# Can a span be a child of an ul and a parent of a li?

Tags: html

From the HTML specs, a `li` must be a child of an `ul`, `ol` or `menu`.

> [Permitted parents: An <ul>, <ol>, or <menu> element. Though not a conforming usage, the obsolete <dir> can also be a parent.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

I need a span between an `ul` and a `li`:

[image: example]

This does not throw any warnings or errors, but is it correct?

Comment: You're asking an [xy question](http://xyproblem.info). Ask about your actual issue instead. Why do you think you need that?

Comment: You can do a lot of... incorrect things in html that aren't officially documented... however the results, given that it's not documented, will generally be unpredictable and should be avoided. In many cases the browser will simply correct your "mistake" for you, resulting in an HTML structure you probably didn't intend.

Answer (score 1):

No. See the docs related to permitted content at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul (and the ones you posted yourself).